# SQL Filter by count of records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of the form: (Answer must work for PostGreSQL 9.2

StateName, ContryName, Pop, etc.  // btw state may also be province, I use them interchangeabley

I would like to remove any country that has too many states

This does a filter, but since I am grouping by the country (states.admin) I get an error because states.name is not in the group clause.

I want a filtered table, that just removes all rows for a country that more than 100 states.

Am I making sense? I assume I need some sort of WHERE subquery.

```
SELECT 
  states.name,
  states.admin
FROM
  vector.states
GROUP BY 
  states.admin
HAVING COUNT(*) < 100
ORDER BY
  states.admin ASC;
```

Comment: How would you find countries with more than 100 states if `state may also be province`? If you take yourself seriously, this question cannot be answered. It's very bad design to write different types of data to the same column while not being able to tell them apart. Also, a question like this needs to provide the table definition, best what you get from psql with `\d vector.states`. Then we'd know which column is the primary key etc.

Comment: It is stated poorly (programmer trying to speak English). I have a table that lists provinces and states. I called the table STATES. But the data is world-wide. But it is the same geographic idea (and that is how the SHAPE file is structured. It has the 2nd level admin boundaries (down one from the country level).

Comment: Still no table definition ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT s.name,s.admin 
FROM states s
INNER JOIN (
SELECT ss.admin
FROM states ss
GROUP BY ss.admin
HAVING COUNT(*) < 100
) a ON a.admin = s.admin
ORDER BY s.admin ASC;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bbbdd/3)</kbd>

Comment: Well the code works, and it is brilliant, but it did not filter what I want. So if you want, here is my revised question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151418/sql-query-to-filter-by-count-and-attribute